# Whats the Appropriate Connection Syntax for PostgreSQL

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, ado.net

I have a C# application currently running with sqlserver as the database. My connection statement using Dapper is stated below:

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))

connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1;Database=Tournaments;Trusted_Connection=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
```

I am trying to get a similar connection string  as above for postgresql  also using Dapper

I have tried the 2 statements below which i thought would be the postgre equivalent of the sqlserver  lines above

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))

connectionString="Server=(localhost:5432);Database=Tournaments;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="Npgsql"/>
```

The system just does not respond. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Npgsql connection string for local Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273385/npgsql-connection-string-for-local-postgres)

Answer (score 0):

Just Try the below connection string. You can use localhost or 127.0.0.1

```
connectionString="Host=127.0.0.1;Port=5432;Database=Tournaments;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="Npgsql"/>
```